# Why did Kyle choose that time in Terminator Genisys

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

Kyle "convinces" Sarah to

> go to 2017 instead of 1997, because Skynet's activation has been delayed

Why doesn't he instead

> go to 2016, or even 15, 14 or earlier? Why wait till the last possible time, if you could have more time to prepare?

I get that it sets up dramatic tension (countdowns!), but is there any coherent in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: A general rule for time travel: the farther back you go, the more stuff you can accidentally mess up and the harder it is to control the results of your changes.  Safety demands going back only as far as you *must* in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Nerrolken they had a huge amount of uncertainty as to what exactly was going on (they didn't even know what genesis was when in the hospital). A few more months to get their bearings wouldn't have hurt. Also, they're going forwards, not backwards. There's no timeline that needs to be kept structurally intact.

Answer (score 3):

They were not going to 2017. Instead,

> they were going to all points between 1997 and 2017 because Pops waited things out in linear time for them for 20 years. Pops was able to do things like work on the construction crew and otherwise prepare.

2017 was just one point in the time period that they were covering.

Also,

> striking in 2017 gave Skynet less time to recover from an attack, and thus promised to maximize results while minimizing risk.

Comment: Indeed. They were simply jumping over the boring bits in an attempts to remain young despite the intervening period. Jumping also has the benefit of making them immune to Skynet sending reinforcements to kill them while they prepare.

Comment: Huh? Pops didn't go at all, they went straight to 2017. They landed on the highway naked in 2017, a few days before Genesys came online. They should have gone to an earlier time to have more preparation.

Comment: @Richard That would explain why they jumped at all, but not why they jumped to a few days before the deadline. Even a month or two would have given them vastly more room to operate while avoiding that all-too predictable countdown.

Comment: @ike - Landing a month earlier gives Skynet a whole month to find them. It's the same reason we don't send paratroops in a couple of months before the main assault.

Comment: "striking in 2017 gave Skynet less time to recover from an attack, and thus promised to maximize results while minimizing risk." First of all, my proposed alternative is "go to 2016, then attack in 2017". Second, why does Skynet have less time as opposed to an attack in 2016? If they destroy Skynet, why would the time matter? There's nothing special about 2017 except that skynet was going to activate then.

Comment: @Richard they were found pretty much right away anyway, but you could argue they wouldn't have known that. Also note that my proposal is what's done in TSCC.

Comment: @Richard so is avoiding skynet for a month really more important than avoiding running up against a deadline? In practice, they were found right away, and would have gained by going earlier. Whether they could have predicted that; I'd argue yes. If you aren't found in the first day, it doesn't seem likely you'd be found later except insofar as you're actually interfering, and they can weight each risk separately as it happens. But what they actually did left them far too little room to do anything interesting.

Comment: @ike - Think of them as paratroops. They land, then strike at the heart of their enemy when he's at his weakest, just before he goes online. If they land early, they could get caught, killed or just plain have an accident.

Comment: @CodeMed And I want them to have gone to 2016 or so and prepared then. Why go straight to a time you know little about and run up against a deadline?

Comment: @Richard if that's what they were after, why not go even later? Drop in 30 seconds to activation and blow the whole thing up with a nuke.

Comment: @ike - Where are they gonna get a nuke from?

Comment: They had a Terminator (Pops) with them, presumably he could steal one over 30 years.

Comment: @CodeMed I still think the reason is dramatic tension. I'm sort of sympathetic to Richard's claim, but not enough to write an answer saying that.